# Excel - How to sum all hours that match one condition in another plan?

Tags: excel

I am trying to do a worksheet to save my work-logs.

By now, this is the problem:

I have these two plans:

[image]

My table in the *Activities-plan*:

[image]

And what I am trying to do in the *Results-plan*:

[image]

How to sum all [@[Total (hours)]] *where* [@[Year-Month]] *matches* [@[Year-Month]] of *both plans*?

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**

The results based on @Amit answer:

New test:

[image]

The results:

[image]

Comment: SUMIF. (comments can't be short, so here's useless text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula for your cell:

```
=SUMIF(Table1[Year-Month],[@[Year-Month]],Table1[Total (hours)])
```

Comment: Maybe formatting. Use "General" formatting. The result should be a some of "full days" + fractions (ie 36 hours is 1.5)

Comment: That's not "General" formatting. general formatting is the standard formatting that shows values as they are. Use that to test.

Comment: The 2015-07 is correct (10/24 = 0.4166...) I can only assume you have some other mistake with 2015-08.

Comment: I found it! I was using `Table1[@[Total (hours)]]` instead of `Table1[Total (hours)]`.. Many thanks !!!